# Mysql search - in which don't have dots

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search MySQL table and get in result in which don't have . (dot). example is below

example1.com

example2.com

example3

example4 com

So i want return, example 3 and 4. So basically i want row which don't have . (dot).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [NOT LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like):

```
SELECT column
FROM tablename
WHERE column NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that @fthiella suggested, or you can filter your search results in this was, using the `stristr` PHP function:

```
<?php

$searchQuery = 'example';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE domain LIKE "%' . mysql_real_escape_string($searchQuery) . '%"';
$query = mysql_query($query);

$total = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($total) {
    $data = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        if(stristr($row['domain'], '.') !== false) {
            $data[] = $row['domain'];
        }
    }

    die('<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>');
} else {
    die('Nothing was found.');
}
```

Note that I don't know your database table structure, so this is a psuedo-example.